# Make my outgoing SPF records strict, and incoming policy lenient (postfix/dovecot)

Tags: email, email-server, spf

I recently added an SPF record to my DNS records, so my email is less likely to be marked as spam.

My SPF record looks like this:

```
mpn.co.         86400   IN  TXT "v=spf1 ip4:45.56.81.114 ip6:2600:3c01::f03c:91ff:fe84:5719 mx -all"
```

My emails send fine, and don't get marked as spam. However, I recently set up a couple forwarding addresses that forward to my @mpn.co email, and they bounced back with this message:

```
host mail.mpn.co[45.56.81.114] said: 550 5.7.1 <xxx@mpn.co>:
    Recipient address rejected: Message rejected due to: SPF fail - not
    authorized.
```

It looks like my mail server is rejecting forwarding addresses. While I want my outgoing email to conform to a strict sending policy, I want people to be able to email me without any problems. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: That _is_ outgoing mail! There is no good solution to this, just don't 'forward" mail in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to change the SPF policy from hardfail (`-all`) to softfail (`~all`). Then your Postfix server should allow the forwarded mail through, though it is more likely to get marked as spam due to the failed check.

Alternatively you can edit your Postfix configuration in `main.cf` to disable the SPF check in `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`. Look for `check_policy_service unix:private/spfcheck` or something like that (details can vary) and remove/comment it. The downside is that you will get more spam as this disables the SPF check for all inbound messages. There is no free lunch.

A third approach could be to add the forwarding servers as valid senders for your domain in the SPF record.